# What does sampling the hidden representation mean

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm doing a course on Neural Networks, which at some point states:

*Sampling the hidden representations regularizes the network by pushing the hidden representation to be binary during the forward pass which limits the modeling capacity of the network.*

What does *Sampling the hidden representations* mean?